# image building fine with docker build, but stat /GO/src/main: no such file or directory encountered with docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile which I can successfully build an image from:

```
FROM iron/go:dev
RUN mkdir /app
COPY src/main/main.go /app/.
# Set an env var that matches your github repo name, replace treeder/dockergo here with your repo name
ENV SRC_DIR=/app
# Add the source code:
ADD . $SRC_DIR
# Build it:
RUN go get goji.io
RUN go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2
RUN cd $SRC_DIR; go build -o main
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
```

However, when I attempt to build the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    expose:
      - '8080'
    container_name: 'api'
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - api-net

  db:
    build: ./db
    expose:
      - '27017'
    container_name: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - api-net

networks:
  api-net:
    driver: bridge
```

I get:

> Removing api mongo is up-to-date Recreating
>
> 532e3cf66460_carsupermarket_api_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for 532e3cf66460_carsupermarket_api_1  Cannot start service
>   api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"/GO/src/main\": stat /GO/src/main:
>   no such file or directory": unknown
>
> ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"/GO/src/main\": stat /GO/src/main: no such file or directory":
>   unknown ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I suspect that docker-compose is introducing some nuance when it comes to directory build paths, however, I'm at a loss as to why my image is building from the docker file when using `docker build .`, but failing when I try to incorporate this into docker-compose.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running the image you've built with the Dockerfile you provided without using the `docker-compose` for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded to the latest version of Docker CE (18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40) and this appears to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Would you edit your question to state your version of Docker you were using, and then the answer to state the version you upgraded to? That might prompt someone to suggest what bug/issue was fixed.